# Regex capture groups divided by a number in between

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to capture 3 groups from a string. The string is in the form the following form:

`{phrase 1} {optional number} {optional phrase 2}`

A few examples of this are:

```
Battery Bank 1
Battery Bank 1 Segments
Battery Bank 1 Warranty Logger
Battery Bank 10
Battery Bank 10 Segments
Battery Bank 10 Warranty Logger
BSU
BSU 1
PCS 3
PCS 1
System
System Meter
```

As you can see, the only mandatory group is the first one which is comprised of word characters and spaces until a number of at least 1 digit appears. Then, optionally, another group of word and spaces characters.

This is what I have so far, but it's not working properly. It's matching over lines. It should match one per line.

```
([a-zA-Z\s]+)(\d+)?(\w)?
```

Here's a regex101 link to play with:
https://regex101.com/r/tSGIEm/2

Comment: Try `^(.*?)(?: +(\d+) *(.*))?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EdfT5e/1).

Comment: Works great and it's much simpler than anubhava's answer? Turn it into a proper answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: I have posted an [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60893934/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(.*?)(?: +(\d+) *(.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EdfT5e/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?: +(\d+) *(.*))?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `+`  - 1+ spaces
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
  - `*`  - 0+ spaces
  - `(.*)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with optional groups:

```
([a-zA-Z]+(?:[ \t]+[a-zA-Z]+)*)(?:[ \t]+(\d+)(?:[  \t]+(.+))?)?
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tSGIEm/7)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `[a-zA-Z]+`: Match a word of 1+ letters
  - `(?:[ \t]+[a-zA-Z]+)*`: Match 0 or more words separated by 1+ spaces/tabs
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group #1

  - `[ \t]+`: Match 1+ spaces or tabs
  - `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits and capture in group #2
  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group #2

    - `[ \t]+`: Match 1+ spaces or tabs
    - `(.+)`: Match 1+ of any characters and capture in group #3
  - `)?`: End *optional* non-capture group #2
- `)?`: End *optional* non-capture group #1